# CentOS 6.9: Nginx not working as reverse proxy with Apache. Error 400 Bad request

Tags: apache, nginx

I ve installed nginx 1.12.1 as a reverse proxy with a working Apache httpd 2.4.25 x64
I have a vmware virtual machine with centOs 6.9. I ve a working stack apache httpd 2.4.25 ---(mod_jk 1.2.42)---Tomcat 7.0.81---(jdbc)---MySQL server 5.7.19. 
Now i ve installed and configure Nginx to work in front of Apache (reverse proxy).
It does not work since three days, (using curl or mozilla browser).
The error message is 400 Bad Request: Request Header Or Cookie Too Large

could someone help me?

Here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.core.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" 
            ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.core.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    client_max_body_size 200M;
    client_body_buffer_size 32k;
    client_header_buffer_size 64k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

my default server config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.http.mydomain.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.http.mydomain.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        root    /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.inc;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;        
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add more details. Add your nginx config and your apache config also

Comment: It is working now. The problem was in the parameter proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; where i did not specified the port. Thank you.